# Uploading JavaScript Blob Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, laravel, mediarecorder-api

I'm trying to record a video (already working) using HTML5 video tag, "getUserMedia" to access the device camera and MediaRecorder API to capture the frames and Angular1 to handle the file uploading. Now I'm having trouble uploading the Blob to my PHP server which is running on Laravel, I currently have 2 ways to upload the video, first is by "ng-click" this works fine but when I programmatically upload the Blob using the same function which "ng-click" run it seems to break the mimeType of my Blob here's how my code looks.

```
$scope.uploader = function() {
    let fData = new FormData();
    let blob = new Blob($scope.chunk, { type: 'video/webm' }); 
    fData.append('vid', blob)
    $http.post(url, fData, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    }, success, error)
})

$timeout(function() {
   $scope.uploader();
}, 10000)
```

This issue here is when the "$scope.uploader()" is called using "ng-click" it works fine but when calling the "uploader" method using the "$timeout" it seems to change the mimeType to "application/octet-stream" which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this code,

```
function base64ToBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
   contentType = contentType || '';
   var sliceSize = 1024;
   var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
   var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
   var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
   var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);
   for (var sliceIndex = 0;sliceIndex <slicesCount;++sliceIndex) {
      var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
      var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);
      var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
      for (var offset = begin, i = 0;offset <end;++i, ++offset) {
        bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
      }
      byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
   }
   return new Blob(byteArrays, {
    type: contentType});
}
```

Define scope

```
$scope.onFile = function(blob) {
    Cropper.encode((file = blob)).then(function(dataUrl) {
    $scope.dataUrl = dataUrl;
    $scope.odataUrl = dataUrl;
    $timeout(showCropper);  // wait for $digest to set image's src
   });
};
```

Submit method

```
 $scope.uploadImage = function () {

                if ($scope.myCroppedImage === '')
                {

                }
                $scope.msgtype = "";
                $scope.msgtxt = "";
                var fd = new FormData();
                var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.myCroppedImage);
                fd.append('clogo', imgBlob);
                fd.append('actionfile', 'editimage');
                $http.post(
                        '../user/user_EditCompany.php',
                        fd, {
                            transformRequest: angular.identity,
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': undefined
                            }
                        }
                )
                        .success(function (response) {
                            // console.log(response);
                            if (response.status == 'success')
                            {
                          //your code
                     }else{ 
                         //your code
                     }
                     })
                        .error(function (response) {
                            console.log('error', response);
                        });
            };

          function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
                var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
                var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                var array = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
                }
                return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
                    type: mimeString
                });
            }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Image? Will this work on Video?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the issue was caused by upload and post limit in my php.ini.